# How do I download a Wave Dashboard JSON file?

Tags: dashboard, einstein-analytics, analytics-cloud

I want to change some things about a Wave Dashboard and for that I have to download, edit and upload a JSON file. According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.bi_dev_guide_xmd.meta/bi_dev_guide_xmd/bi_xmd_intro.htm): "You can download the existing XMD file from the Edit page". XMD = kind of JSON. But how do I do that? I cannot find a way to do it.

Comment: I tried the "Enable Flex Dashboard Designer (Beta)" setting, but that just changes the UI of the designer, not the features. Still no option to download an XMD file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not going to believe this. I was reading the Wave Analytics Dashboard JSON Guide, and it states:

"To create advanced dashboards, you typically modify the JSON file that defines a dashboard.
1. In your browser’s address bar, type the URL of the Create Lens page. For example, if your
Salesforce instance is na3.salesforce.com, type
https://na3.salesforce.com/insights/web/lens.apexp in your browser’s
address bar."

So I did that, and then you end up in a screen with a red message:

"Note: Dashboards and lenses opened, created, or saved in the Spring ‘16 release or later won't appear on this page. Instead, use expert editor mode. Open the dashboard or lens you want to edit, and press CTRL+E (PC) or CMD+E (Mac)"

So I opened my Wave dashboard, the way I always do, via Wave Analytics. I already knew how to get in the normal Edit mode (click the button or press E), but now I pressed Ctrl+E and voila, it shows me a JSON text editor, with the file that I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to change the dashboard JSON, or the Extended Metadata (XMD) JSON? Two different files, with two different purposes. The Dashboard JSON is used to customize the page layout: what type of charts, how are they spaced, types of queries ran. For this, use the instruction already posted: CTRL + E

However, if you're looking for the XMD file to change the dataset (to change API to label name, measuring units, colors of fields...). From your app page, hover over the desired data set, and an EDIT button will appear. Click it. And download the first file [Add Extended Metadata File (JSON)], edit it using the "Wave Analytics Extended Metadata (XMD) Reference" as a reference. And upload it back into the dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought all Wave JSON files were XMD, but apparently not. I removed the XMD references. I was really looking for the Dashboard JSON file. As for the dataset JSON file: I cannot download this, I always get a file just consisting of {}. I also noticed this issue with someone else, in a different org. The only way for me to get a dataset JSON file is to save it while creating a dataset in Dataset Builder.

Comment: THis is my case too - I just get a file of {} - has this been raised as a bug?